# jQuery's cloned elements lose click events after being removed and appended to a container twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6poures/

```
item.click(function()
{
    alert("It works")
})

$("#container").append(item)

var stored = item.clone(true, true)

function add_remove()
{
    $("#container").html("")
    $("#container").append(stored)
}
```

Basically, if I clone an element with .clone(true, true), after I replace the container with .html and appended again, and  repeat that process again, the click event is gone.

Is there something wrong with jQuery or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have event listeners in content you add dynamically, it usually simplifies things to use event delegation instead. This means that you attach the event listener to a parent container that is not deleted - in this case your `#container` element - and you use a selector in the jQuery `.on()` call to specify which child elements you are interested in.

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6poures/1/) that illustrates the technique for your use case, and here it is as a snippet:

```js
$("#container").on( "click", "#item", function() {
 alert("It works")
})

var html = "<div id='item'>Hi</div>"

$("#container").html(html)

function add_remove() {
 $("#container").html(html)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>

<br>

<button onclick="add_remove()">
  Remove And Add Again
</button>
```

Note that the code doesn't even use `.clone()` now; it just inserts the HTML code each time without worrying about event listeners at all. You *could* use `.clone()` as in your original code, but event delegation gives you the flexibility to do it either way. In any case you wouldn't need the `.clone(true,true)` arguments because you don't care about preserving event listeners in the inserted code.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I was doing a click event for every message in a chat system, doing this will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code (have made minor changes to your code, to make it work). You don't even need to `clone()`:

```js
var item = $("<div id='item'>Hi</div>");

$("#container").on('click', '#item', function() {
  alert("It works");
});

$("#container").append(item);

function add_remove() {
  $("#container").html("").append(item);
  alert('cloned and appended successfully.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>

<br>

<button onclick="add_remove()">
  Remove And Add Again
</button>
```